# Is 'Automatically fill in Access text boxes based on a combo box selection' gonna work for a calculated type Field?

Tags: database, ms-access

I have 3 tables (Storage, Sold, Order)
I want to get order Form values from storage table with a combo Box
it works fine with the other fields
but when it comes to the calculated Fields

I get this Error
'Run-time error '2448':

you cant assign value to this object'

And for the comboBox on Change

i use this code
Me.txtPrice.Value= Me.Combo27.Column(5)

can anyone help me solve this

or have a better solution for auto populate fields?

Comment: Please give us a more complete code and data example. I cannot debug one single line of code.

Comment: Does it show value in column 5 when you dropdown the combobox?

Comment: Harun24HR   No it doesnt . When i add the column 5 code i get the error message

Comment: NXP5Z       Whatch this vedio                                                                                                                   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rSPS24EfijI&t=572s

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: what's the `ControlSource` of the field `txtPrice` you're trying to update? It should be an updateable field, or unbound.

Comment: Cannot set Value of a Calculated field, If by "calculated" you mean a Calculated type field in table. Is txtPrice a textbox bound to a Calculated field or a normal field?

Comment: June7   yes, sorry i meant calculated type and   the its bound to a calculated field

Comment: jbud  i have the same field (price) in the storage table and I don't want to write it every time in the order table too.    But where should look for the Updateable and  Unbound ?